# RoR use url w/o port 3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

What's the easiest way to point domain.com to my RoR app?  When I don't include the port, ie `domain.com:3000` it lists the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apache, you need to use a rails mod to get it working. The best one is [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). It is very easy to set up, follow their directions, set up your virtual host and you'll be on your way. Again, apache cannot serve rails apps without extra additions.

It sounds like you are getting the mongrel/webrick servers that you run with `ruby script/server` or `rails server` confused with apache. In production don't even bother with webrick or mongrel if you've got apache running. Install Passenger. Then its easy, just go to your conf file and add your VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /webapps/mysite/public
    <Directory /webapps/mysite/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've fooled with this all day.  I'm not sure what's happening, but maybe it's a apache/webrick conflict?  If it is, how can I correct this problem?!

Comment: First, no webrick. Don't run it, thats one reason you are having a problem. If you want to use apache, shut down webrick and install passenger. Its very simple to deploy an app to apache if you follow the instructions on the passenger site.

Comment: K. I stopped webrick, re-installed passenger, and restarted apache...but I still have to go to port 3000 to see my rails app...